# CakePHP 3 server returns false when running request/response

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

After I put my cakephp 3.x project online, I get 'string (1) "0"' as return from the index.php file inside the webroot folder.

This is the part that will returns false:

```
// Bind your application to the server.
$server = new Server(new Application(dirname(__DIR__) . '/config'));

// Run the request/response through the application
// and emit the response.
$server->emit($server->run()); // -> returns false
```

I've checked the error log on the server and did some debugging but can't find a solution to fix this. When I run this project on my local machine (MAMP)it works fine.

**Update 2019-02-09:**

After doing another debug session I found that the 'string () "0"' is produced by the method below. This Runner.php class is located at ***'/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/Http/Runner.php'***. But I can't find some strange differences between my local and server environment met dumping the `$request` or `$response`. Also the `$middleware` is not different.

The method's from the *Runner.php* class:

```
 /**
     * @param \Cake\Http\MiddlewareQueue $middleware The middleware queue
     * @param \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request The Server Request
     * @param \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response The response
     * @return \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface A response object
     */
    public function run($middleware, ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $this->middleware = $middleware;
        $this->index = 0;

        // this method produced the 'string (1) "0"'. But why??
        return $this->__invoke($request, $response);
    }

    /**
     * @param \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface $request The server request
     * @param \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface $response The response object
     * @return \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface An updated response
     */
    public function __invoke(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response)
    {
        $next = $this->middleware->get($this->index);
        if ($next) {
            $this->index++;

            return $next($request, $response, $this);
        }

        // End of the queue
        return $response;
    }
```

Comment: `\Cake\Http\Server::emit()` doesn't return anything. If your script _echoes_ `0`, then check for `die()` and `exit()` calls in the code, maybe you can trace things down that way already, alternatively use a debugger with step through functionality, set a few breakpoints and step through the code until you reach the code responsible for the output, then trace your way back. Also make sure that you enable debug mode, and check your server and (Cake)PHP error logs.

Comment: I've updated my question. I've also checked for ` die() ` or `exit() ` but found nothing. Also the error logs are not producing any message.

Comment: That method certainly doesn't produce the output, it's what is being invoked from there, ie your middleware stack as defined in `Application::middleware()`, which basically means, your whole application. This is what you need to step into with a debugger. Just so that I don't misunderstand this, do you get the output `0`, ie just that one single digit, or do you get the output that actually says `string (1) "0"`?

Comment: When I dump this `var_dump($next($request, $response, $this));` it will display 'string(1) "0"'